# xamarin camera app does not want to run as a default camera app

Tags: xamarin

I have xamarin custom camera application, now need to run the camera app a default camera. the trick is the camera works but when I try to access it as a default camera, it doesn't appear. I have check online without any luck. And my manifest file seems ok, but it does not want to appear, when I want to choose it as a default camera on my device.

```
xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="auto" package="Meniko_Cam.Meniko_Cam" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
  <!--suppress UsesMinSdkAttributes-->
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <application android:name="android.app.Application" android:allowBackup="true" android:label="Meniko_Cam.Meniko_Cam" android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:label="Meniko Camera" android:name="md520776b34c29868a8e2c9da76ebebad64.MainActivity">
      <intent-filter android:icon="@drawable/icon">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <provider android:name="mono.MonoRuntimeProvider" android:exported="false" android:initOrder="2147483647" android:authorities="Meniko_Cam.Meniko_Cam.mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.__mono_init__" />
    <!--suppress ExportedReceiver-->
    <receiver android:name="mono.android.Seppuku">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="mono.android.intent.action.SEPPUKU" />
        <category android:name="mono.android.intent.category.SEPPUKU.Meniko_Cam.Meniko_Cam" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: What IntentFilters do you have? Please post relevant information from your resulting manifest found in obj/android

Comment: Hi check the resulting manifest for the camera application

Comment: Any reason you have two MainActivities and only one of them has the IntentFilters? Did you add the filters yourself? Or are you using the `[IntentFilter]` attribute?

Comment: yes I did add filters myself, basically the camera is working just he part of choose it as a default does not want to work. Cause with regard to the manifest I did follow the guidelines regarding it, just did not know if I was on the right path.

Comment: Your manifest is wrong then. Add the IntentFilters with the Attribute

Comment: Ok I have corrected the manifest now, which looks like this now(WILL BE SENT NOW). Do i still need to add another intent filter that will require the camera app to display on device and choose it as a default camera